# screenshot only the active monitor on ubuntu/debian

Tags: ubuntu, display, multi-monitor, screenshot

I would like to do screenshots of the active monitor (the one on which my mouse is) or screenshots of always the same monitor ; and not the two monitors at the same time.

Is there any command/option that would let me do this?

I'm not interested in cropping each of my screenshot, even with a script (since I'm using them in parallel and I do a lot of them), neither grabing a selected area, (since I need them to be taken from the same place, with the same size).

For now, I unplug my second monitor but this is very uncomfortable.

Comment: I assume using the "select area to grab" is not an option either? How would you define "active monitor"? On extended desktop setups, there is no such thing.

Comment: Indeed, taking a specific area is not comfortable as well (since I need all my screen shot to be the same size and position).

Comment: Editing the question about "active monitor"

Comment: Mint ... but I think we shall find a solution via the command line so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, what _could_ matter is what desktop environment you're using. Gnome, cinnamon. xfce, kde, something else? I have removed the distro tags, please add the relevant DE tag.

Comment: @Braiam I did crosspost since the question could have more answers from the ubuntu stack-exchange (even if it the solution is not linked to ubutnu). I couldn't put only a link in the question body so I copy/pasted the question ... let me edit that to be clear to next readers

Comment: @Jav crossposting is actively discouraged. Please either delete one of the two, or edit to differentiate them. Make the [ubuntu.se] one clearly about unity or Ubuntu and this one into a more general *nix question.

Comment: done ... let's go back to the question then :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I just found [`shutter`](http://shutter-project.org/about/), a nifty tool that can do this. You can install on Debian-based systems with

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Then, once you launch `shutter`, take your screenshot limiting it to the active monitor only:
[image]

I just checked and it works perfectly on my LMDE running Cinnamon, it correctly took screenshots of the monitor where my mouse was displayed.

Comment: perfect ! I wanted to avoid installing those 50 new packets needed but that was worth it.

Comment: Looks like the tool was discontinued and removed from Ubuntu18+ repos.
It can still be installed (*I use Ubuntu 20.x*) using another PPA, see https://itsfoss.com/install-shutter-ubuntu/
Also, according to some comment posted 2 weeks ago, the development might have started again.

Comment: I needed this to work on the command line since I use the `print screen` key as a hotkey to take screenshots. Looks like the `-a` combined with `-f` does what I want. Here's my command for an example: `shutter -a -f -o screenshot_%Y-%m-%d_%T.png`